# BLDC Motor Controller Failure

Tags: noise, brushless-dc-motor, level-shifting, over-voltage-protection

I am developing a robotic vehicle that has four BLDC scooter-style motors that are controlled by off-the-shelf, dual-motor controllers. I have had several of the controllers fail and am trying to determine if there is something inherent to my system design that is the problem or if it is within the controller itself. I am still performing my own investigations, but any recommendations would be appreciated.

**System Overview**

My design uses two motor controllers (one each for front/rear motors). Two identical, custom ECUs are responsible for the control signals, one for each controller. There are separate PWM (10 kHz) signals for throttle and brake, GPIO for direction, and a capture line for speed feedback. The wires between the controllers and the ECUs are unshielded and are around one foot long. A 36 V Li-Ion battery (limited to 30-40 V) is the power source for the vehicle.

The motor controller is a JYQD_YL02D. The "datasheet" is a jpg image, so I have included some information below, some of which has been obtained from conversations with the manufacturer. I can provide further information upon request. As a side note, I am already working on switching to a more reputable controller, but I have several MVP vehicles in the field that I need to maintain up until the switch. Plus, if my design is at fault, I need to fix it regardless.

The controllers have an input voltage range of 10-42 V and locally convert battery voltage to 5 V for its control electronics. There is an independent set of the input and output lines (rated to 5.5 V) for each motor. The throttle and brake inputs may be controlled with either analog or PWM. The direction input is a binary high/low signal. The speed feedback is a square wave with a frequency proportional to wheel speed.

The ECU is built around an ESP32. Level shifter circuits are used to convert between the ESP's 3.3 V and the motor controller’s 5 V. The speed input uses a simple 1k/2k voltage divider. The three output lines use two [AO3400A](https://aosmd.com/sites/default/files/res/data_sheets/AO3400A.pdf) N-channel MOSFETS for conversion (see below).

[image: ECU output level shifter. MTR_RBRK is directly connected to a GPIO pin. RBRK is connected to an output connector. Q7 and Q9 are AO3400A N-channel MOSFETs.]

The ECU's 5 V supply is provided by a [LD1086](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ld1086.pdf) LDO with 10 uF MLCC input and output capacitors. The input is a 12 V supply generated external to the ECU. Besides level shifting, the ECU has CAN and RS485 transceivers that use 5 V. Note that the ESP's 3.3 V supply is stepped down from 12 V by a second LD1086 and does not directly impact the 5 V conversion.

[image: ECU 5 V supply LDO. +12 V is generated external to the ECU.]

**Failures**

Two main failure modes have been observed so far:

1. The motor controller’s high and/or low MOSFETs for a motor phase fail closed with the gate, drain, and source shorted together. There was one instance where all of the phase MOSFETs heated enough for the solder joints to reflow (though only one phase had shorted). The controllers have built-in stall/overcurrent protection that likely failed in this instance, but I am not certain.
2. One or both of the motor controller’s main control ICs internally shorts 5V to GND. Both direction control output signals on the ECU will infrequently develop a simultaneous short or low resistance connection to ground due to a failure of MOSFET Q9 in the above control signal schematic.

Failure 2 is the most frequent failure with failure 1 occurring roughly half as often. Only one of the two typically occurs, but there have been infrequent cases of both. I do not know if dual occurrences were simultaneous or if the second developed after continued operation with the initial failure.

There have been a few instances where both motor controllers in the vehicle simultaneously fail. Only failure 2 has been confirmed to have a simultaneous failure, but there is one instance that I suspect was simultaneous failure 1 occurrence.

I have not yet checked to see if failure 1 is associated with damage to the control pins from the main control IC.

Failures have occurred at various speeds and vibration levels. There is not a clear age of the system before the failures occur.

**Current Hypotheses**

The motor controller manufacturer has suggested that the likely cause for both failures is that the control inputs from the ECU have unstable voltages that occasionally exceed 5.5 V. I have not yet checked voltage stability at the ECU nor the motor controller during operation.

As second possibility is that the input voltage for the entire motor controller exceeds maximum ratings. The controller has a circuit to dump excess energy through a resistor, but I have observed that it is possible for input voltage to exceed 50 V when braking near top of charge, but it has not been determined how it behaves at the time of controller failure. The supplier has stated that the controller is rated to 42 V. Notably, the capacitors across the input lines are only rated to 50 V. It is unknown if other components may be operating near or above their voltage ratings.

I am currently investigating the control signal overvoltage as the more likely cause. I plan to investigate both the ECU side and the controller side in an attempt to determine any noise being introduced. I am most suspicious of the 5 V stability at the ECU, but the fact that there have been a few simultaneous failures of both controllers (reminder that each has a separate ECU) makes me suspect that there is something else that is at least aggravating the underlying problem. In addition, I have had failures with an older ECU design that used 3.3 V control signals.

Comment: Use twisted pair all over and for long logic add 50 ~100 ohms series to dampen inductive resonance.  Long acceleration periods can draw up to 10x rated power unless acceleration or current is limited which may cause rapid jcn . temp rise.  Lack of dead-time under any mismatch of component delays with temp rise will be catastrophic shoot-through.

Comment: 10kHz 8-bit PWM gives you a minimum pulse period of 392ns (100μs period divided into 255 slices). When driving Q7's 630pF gate with 3.3V through 680Ω, it takes around 433ns to reach \$V_{gp}\$ (where \$I_{ds}\$ reaches its peak but \$V_{ds}\$ is still at its maximum) and another 140ns for it to reach the end of the Miller plateau (where \$V_{ds}\$ is at its minimum and the MOSFET is full on). Q9 experiences the same slow rise time but has an extra switching delay time due to Q7's \$V_{ds}\$ taking >500ns to appreciably drop. Swap the MOSFET logic level converter for a proper buffer IC.

Comment: How do the batteries connect to the motor drivers? If there’s any diode in that power path the dc link voltage will skyrocket during deceleration